# getting an error associated with WSAIoctl

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

hey guys i have been trying to make a simple console application to see my network traffic :P im trying to just read it.

anyways im getting an error from the WSAIoctl function and the error code WSAGetLastError is giving me is 10022 and the MSDN tells me that it is associated with this:

Invalid argument.
Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not listening.

i have tried messing with the arguments without luck :/ please help me :P

here's my code:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
int startup = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsaData);

if(startup != 0) {
    cout << "Error: could not initalize WSADATA for target socket." << endl;
    system("pause");
}

unsigned long BytesReturned;
int InBuffer, OutBuffer, LPCVoid;
int optValue = 1;
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);

Sleep(await);
cout << "creating and configuring RAW_SOCK" << endl;

int listening = listen(sock, SOMAXCONN); // tried debugging using this.
int sockopt = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, 2, (char*)&optValue, sizeof(optValue));
int SockMode = WSAIoctl(sock, SIO_RCVALL, &InBuffer, sizeof(InBuffer), &OutBuffer, sizeof(OutBuffer), &BytesReturned, NULL, NULL);
//0x98000001
if(SockMode == 0) {
    Sleep(await);
    cout << "RAW_SOCKET created successfully!" << endl << "Trying to listen for incoming network packets..." << endl;
    int listeningk = listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);

    if(listening == 0) {
        Sleep(await);
        cout << "socket listening without problems, looking for incoming request..." << endl;
    }
    else {
        Sleep(await);
        cout << "Error: could not listen on socket." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
else {
    Sleep(await);
    cout << "Error: could not create RAW_SOCKET..." << endl << "Dumping SockMode!\r\nint SockMode = " << SockMode << endl;
    cout << "setsockopt = " << sockopt << endl; 
    cout << "WSAGetLastError: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: In addition to what @SteveTownsend said, creating a `SOCK_RAW` socket requires admin privileges, but you are not checking if `socket()` is successful before using the socket.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548.aspx: "Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later."

Answer (score 0):

Your socket needs to be bound before you can listen.  Moreover for this `WSAIoctl` option you have to obey (from the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

> The socket also must be bound to an explicit local IPv4 or IPv6
>   interface, which means that you cannot bind to INADDR_ANY or
>   in6addr_any.

I'd suggest some basic self-education is in order before trying to progress this code.  There are code samples for common ops like socket setup in MSDN.

Comment: naa i like learning this way :P i already know several languages so i find that im learning C++ fast, only been working with it for like 2-3 weeks and the only line i have a problem with is the one above, and it makes sense to me that i should have binded it :L had similar problems with C# before

Comment: Also, creating `SOCK_RAW` sockets requires admin privileges: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548.aspx) "Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later."